# How to do you call a function inside separated class?

Tags: c++

So, I tried to make this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class BuckysClass{
public:
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }

    string getName(){
        return name;
    }

private:
    string name;

};

int main()
{

BuckysClass bo;
bo.setName("Buckingham Palace");
cout << bo.getName();

return 0;

}
```

BECOMING TO A SEPARATED CLASS like this :

```
#include "BuckysClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main (){

BuckysClass bo;
bo.setName("Buckingham Palace");
cout << bo.getName();

return 0;
}
```

==============

```
#ifndef BUCKYSCLASS_H
#define BUCKYSCLASS_H


class BuckysClass
{
public:
   void setName(string x);
   string getName();
private:
    string name;
};

#endif // BUCKYSCLASS_H
```

=============

```
#include "BuckysClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

BuckysClass::BuckysClass()
{
}

void setName(string x){
    name = x;
}

string getName(){
    return name;
}
```

When I run the first code, I succeed,
but I got error when running the separated class code,

help me find out what's wrong ???

I tried to use different code,
but it seems I can't find the reason,
the closest reason I believe, is the main doesnt call the function on the separated class properly.

Comment: Which error did you get? The compiler error can really help...

Comment: Add the class name before the member function name in your cpp file: `void BuckysClass::setName(string x){`

Comment: Please post also error you get.

Comment: And it's not _inside a separated class_, it's the same class with the function definitions in a separated file

Comment: It seems you have not accepted any answers in your questions ever, so take a look at this post:[Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) to learn more about accepting and upvote. You can accept a post as answer by click the check-mark near the post. While you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answers as you find useful, including the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write this code:

```
void setName(string x){
    name = x;
}

string getName(){
    return name;
}
```

The compiler interprete it as two functions called `setName` and `getName`, it has no idea they are member functions of your `BuckysClass` class.

You have to precise it with the following syntax:

```
void BuckysClass::setName(string x){
    name = x;
}

string BuckysClass::getName(){
    return name;
}
```

---

Additionally, here you are defining a default constructor:

```
BuckysClass::BuckysClass()
{
}
```

But you didn't put it in the class prototype. You have to add it somewhere in the class prototype definition in your .h file, or your compiler won't recognize it:

```
class BuckysClass
{
public:
   BuckysClass(); // Default constructor.

   void setName(string x);
   string getName();
private:
    string name;
};
```